# Block UI, until jquery dialog dismissed

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to block UI background (not scrollable ...), until jquery dialog is dimissed (which I do this in dialog)

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: `$('body').css('overflow','hidden');` ??? Even there is some bug on webkit, you should try it and see if it fits your needs. But wait, what have you tried so far???

Comment: open your dialog in `Jquery Modal PopUp`

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal & http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: @ArunPJohny even with modal, on webkit you can still scroll the body using mouse wheel or keyboard arrows, as i can test it http://jsfiddle.net/v3yp6/  EDIT: indeed, on all browsers

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
$('div#selector').bind('open', function(event) {
   // block
});

$('div#selector').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
   // unblock
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using open/close callback of dialog to set CSS property `overflow` of BODY:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrdK2/)

```
open: function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
},
close: function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
}
```